# Excel VBA Pass Worksheet Name as Variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to pass a worksheet name in as a variable to the following VBA. I am obviously doing something wrong because I keep getting Invalid Qualifier errors. This function works when I have the actual sheet name in it, but I want to be able to use it with different worksheets. Thanks!

```
Function fnGetRowNumSNCT(ByVal valueToFind As Long, SheetName As String) As Long
   
    Dim matchResult As Variant

    matchResult = Application.Match(valueToFind, SheetName.Columns(1), 0)
    

    If Not IsError(matchResult) Then
       fnGetRowNumSNCT = matchResult
    End If
    
End Function

The sub routine that calls it is this:
Private Sub cmdView_Click()

'open SNCT form to selected record

'On Error goto Err_cmdView_Click

Dim lngRecID As Long
Dim lngRowNum As Long
Dim strMRN As String
Dim strSheetName As String

'get selected recordID
For i = 0 To lstSNCT.ListCount - 1
    If lstSNCT.Selected(i) = True Then
        lngRecID = strSelectedItems & lstSNCT.List(i)
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

strSheetName = "Sheet3"
lngRowNum = fnGetRowNumSNCT(lngRecID, strSheetName)
```

Comment: `Worksheets(SheetName).Columns(1)`

Comment: It's better to pass a `Worksheet` object than to pass a sheet name, IMO. Also, you want to qualify the workbook said worksheet is in, e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName)`.

Comment: From where are you calling this function?  Are you calling it from a vba sub or from the worksheet as a UDF?

Comment: When I use Worksheets(SheetName).Columns(1) I get Subscript out of range error.  I have also tried ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Columns(1) and get same out of range error.  I am calling this from the code behind a VBA UserForm

strSheetName = "Sheet3"
lngRowNum = fnGetRowNumSNCT(lngRecID, strSheetName)

Comment: That is a VBA Sub

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include the sub that calls this function.

Comment: What does it actually mean "This function works when I have the actual sheet name in it"? Example, pls.

Comment: The following is my code.  I apologize if I'm not posting it correctly... This is my first time posting.

Private Sub cmdView_Click()

'open SNCT form to selected record

'On Error goto Err_cmdView_Click

Dim lngRecID As Long
Dim lngRowNum As Long
Dim strMRN As String
Dim strSheetName As String

'get selected recordID
For i = 0 To lstSNCT.ListCount - 1
    If lstSNCT.Selected(i) = True Then
        lngRecID = strSelectedItems & lstSNCT.List(i)
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

strSheetName = "Sheet3"
lngRowNum = fnGetRowNumSNCT(lngRecID, strSheetName)

Comment: This cannot possibly work with the function presented above in your question!

Comment: Hello Gene, thanks for your response.  Can you tell me why this won't work?  I'm  used to working in MS Access, this is my first time trying to write VBA in Excel.

Comment: "SheetName As String" --> a "String" variable does not have "Columns" property --> compilation error is what you should get. "Worksheet" object has "Columns" and so does "Range" object... Excel built-in objects are different from what Access has. The key is to study them well. Some comment above suggest passing Worksheet object which is generally a good suggestion but pointless here as well. Also, WorksheetFunctions are a bit touchy when used via VBA. Here, Match will err if no match found --> execution will stop: you need to use  "On Error" before that line, and then examine for an error...

Comment: Personally, I would pass a Range (full column) and use Range.Find (assign to a range object, say R). If R is Not Nothing Then fnGetRowNumSNCT = R.Row

Comment: And do declare ALL variables :)

Answer (score 0):

### Return Row of Found Number (ID) in First Column

**Worksheet**

```vb
Option Explicit

Function fnGetRowNumSNCT( _
    ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
    ByVal SearchInteger As Long) _
As Long
    If ws Is Nothing Then Exit Function
  
    Dim RowNum As Variant
    RowNum = Application.Match(SearchInteger, ws.Columns(1), 0)
    
    If IsNumeric(RowNum) Then
        fnGetRowNumSNCT = RowNum
    End If
    
End Function

Private Sub cmdView_Click()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Dim lngRecID As Long: lngRecID = 3
    
    Dim lngRowNum As Long: lngRowNum = fnGetRowNumSNCT(ws, lngRecID)
    
    If lngRowNum > 0 Then
        MsgBox "'RecID' found in row " & lngRowNum, vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "'RecID' not found.", vbCritical
    End If
    
End Sub
```

You could also consider one of the following solutions.

**Workbook**

- Here you could consider putting the `wb` argument last and making it optional...

  ```
  Optional ByVal wb As Workbook
  ```

  ... and adding an if statement...

  ```
  If wb Is Nothing Then
      Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  End If
  ```

  ... or just removing it completely and instead hard-code `ThisWorkbook` into the function:

  ```
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(WorksheetName)
  ```

```vb
Function fnGetRowNumSNCTWorkbook( _
    ByVal wb As Workbook, _
    ByVal WorksheetName As String, _
    ByVal SearchNumber As Long) _
As Long
    If wb Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(WorksheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The worksheet '" & WorksheetName & "' doesn't exist.", _
            vbCritical
        Exit Function
    End If
       
    Dim RowNum As Variant
    RowNum = Application.Match(SearchNumber, ws.Columns(1), 0)
    
    If IsNumeric(RowNum) Then
        fnGetRowNumSNCTWorkbook = RowNum
    End If
    
End Function

Sub TestWorkbook()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim lngRecID As Long: lngRecID = 3
    
    Dim lngRowNum As Long
    lngRowNum = fnGetRowNumSNCTWorkbook(wb, "Sheet1", lngRecID)
    
    If lngRowNum > 0 Then
        MsgBox "'RecID' found in row " & lngRowNum, vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "'RecID' not found.", vbCritical
    End If
    
End Sub
```

**Range**

```vb
Function fnGetRowNumSNCTRange( _
    ByVal rg As Range, _
    ByVal SearchNumber As Long) _
As Long
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    Dim RowNum As Variant: RowNum = Application.Match(SearchNumber, rg, 0)
    
    If IsNumeric(RowNum) Then
        fnGetRowNumSNCTRange = RowNum
    End If
    
End Function

Sub TestRange()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' Note that an error will occur if 'Sheet3' doesn't exist.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Columns(1)
    ' Or just (not recommended):
    'Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Columns(1)
    Dim lngRecID As Long: lngRecID = 3
    
    Dim lngRowNum As Long: lngRowNum = fnGetRowNumSNCTRange(rg, lngRecID)
    
    If lngRowNum > 0 Then
        MsgBox "'RecID' found in row " & lngRowNum, vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "'RecID' not found.", vbCritical
    End If
    
End Sub
```